# how to split number in digits and add a character in between

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Input : `2134`
Desired Output : `21:34`

How to get that result with PIG?

Comment: Write UDFs. Should be easy.

Comment: Is that Hour and Minute ? Format the string if so

Answer (score 0):

```
output_relation = foreach input_relation generate CONCAT(SUBSTRING((chararray)Number,0,2),':',SUBSTRING((chararray)Number,2,4)) ;
```

above code will give you (:) between no, I have taken 2134 as (Number:Int)